# Show authentication dialog inside webview android

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

i have an URL, this url open the authentication dialog similar when you try to access the router admin page of your router.
In my case when in load url in webview it goes outside may application and open android native web brower and display the dialog.
i want to make it remain in my application for further processing.

Just as the Web Brower open route's authentication page.

Answer (score 0):

Update the definition of your `WebView` to this :

```
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // in case you are using javascript
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true); 
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then the WebView will be able to create many pages, and not load new ones in the native browser.

Comment: its not working for me... A Dialog box for authenication should be display where i enter username and password and on proceed to next. 
As you have mention in apply it remains in app but doesnot display.

Comment: I added just this line ´webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);´  in my code. can you try again?

Comment: I updated the code . have you tried already ? Is it working now ?